# Does the 3D sculpting machine in Mission Impossible III exist?

Tags: realism, effects, mission-impossible

In Mission Impossible III at 48 minutes in there is a scene in which they make one of the signature Mission Impossible latex face masks using a portable sculpting machine to create the pattern. Does this kind of machine really exist or is it fantastic?

[image]

Comment: It's less complicated than 3D-printing, so why should it not exist?

Comment: Yes and no. It's a CNC machine but no one make them that small because moving parts cannot be THAT small. https://www.dunagroup.com/usa/products/foams/corafoam-prop-foam

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY Doesn't look like any CNC machine I have ever seen. What model are you are referring to?

Comment: "... or is it fantastic?" - It sure is fantastic. Real? I don't know. :P

Comment: @TylerDurden In the link I used there, a pciture with firefighter show the machine on robot arm that can move in 3 dimensions. Their machine is just very, very specialized which almost no company will do because it's just non-economical.

Answer (score 1):

A CNC machine could do the same thing. It's a 3D printer, however latex is a tricky substance since it starts off liquid and requires time to cure. So the machine would work, but far slower than the movie.